# How to localize image in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I follow this example to localize img: 
http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/pub/?0

which works. There is just one problem. I need to have image in package where I have java classes what I dont like. How I can set path to webapp/img ?

I try to set:

```
    add(new Image("work", new PackageResourceReference(StatisticPage.class, "/img/work.png")));
```

or

```
    add(new Image("work", new PackageResourceReference(StatisticPage.class, "img/work.png")));
```

but with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ContextImage` instead of `Image`.

Comment: can you give me some example ? Because when I change it then localization doesnt work

Comment: You are right, it won't work automatically anymore. You'd need to parse the filename yourself and add the current locale to it. But I would simply create a Java package with a class MyResources and all the resource files in it and use PackageResourceReference(MyResources.class, "img/work.png");

Answer (score 2):

Use a [ContextRelativeResource](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/request/resource/ContextRelativeResource.html).